# Creating a numpy array from a method using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy-array as input for a basic sigmoid-classifier.
I would like the classifier to return an array with the probabilities.

```
import numpy as np


def sigmoid(x):
    sigm = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return sigm


def p(D, w, b):
    prob=sigmoid(np.dot(D[:][7],w)+b)
    return prob
```

How can I change p() so that it returns a 1D numpy array with the probabilities listed in order of the input data ?

Atm "prob" is an array of length 14, however the input array "D" is over 400 in size, so there is an error somewhere in the logic.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `D`,`w` and `b`?

Comment: b is the bias of the function (int); w can be a numpy array or an int; D is a Matrix (2D array), however for now only the data in column 7 is important for the function

Comment: I understand this, but are the dimensions of  `D` 400x14 for example? In this case, you'd be multiplying a single vector of length 14. To get the column, you'd have to do  `D[:,7] `.

Comment: You are indeed correct and this just solved it. Thank you. If you write it as an answer I will mark it correct, so it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The issue is the incorrect slicing of the array. One has to use `D[:,7]` instead of `D[:][7]` to extract a column.

---

Perhaps like this:

```
import numpy as np


def sigmoid(x):
    sigm = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return sigm


def p(D, w, b):
    prob=sigmoid(np.dot(D[:][7],w)+b)
    return np.ravel(prob)
```

Comment: prob already is an array. np.ravel() does not change anything. I will clarify the question.

Comment: That `[:]` is superfluous.